# Freemarker Template nested interpolation

Tags: nested, freemarker

In my Freemarker template I am calling a static function sha1Hex from org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.

I am trying to generate hash for a label in an XML documents.

```
${digestUtil.sha1Hex(doc.names.name)}
```

The following works : `${digestUtil.sha1Hex("John Deer")}` as expected.

How can I use nested interpolation?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: If `doc.names.name` evaluates correctly to a string then the code you wrote will work.

Comment: Since FreeMarker resolves doc.names.name as ElementModel, the call to digestUtil.sha1Hex was failing. This works: ${digestUtil.sha1Hex(doc.names.name.@@text)}